# What is this part

Tags: sql, sql-server, command

I found the following SQL command:

```
Dim commandText As String = _
     "UPDATE Sales.Store SET Demographics = @demographics " _
     & "WHERE CustomerID = @ID;"
```

What is the part that says `Sales.Store`?

**EDIT**

So what would be the correct path for my situation?

[image]

I'm doing this all in ASP.net inside of MSVS2010 if that helps at all...

Comment: Unless Sales is a schema, this looks wrong to me.  I would nomrally expect to see `Sales.dbo.Store` or `Sales..Store`.

Comment: @Joel: not all databases distinguish between database and schema.

Comment: Response to EDIT = right click on contentTable and select properties, it should tell you the schema then the path is [schema].ContentTable.   probably dbo.ContentTable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `Sales` - database or schema name (I would bet for database name because historically in MS SQl schemas used very rare as opposed to Oracle)
- `Store` - table or view name

In any statement (MS Sql Server) access object definition is

```
<object> ::=
{ 
    [ server_name . database_name . schema_name . 
    | database_name .[ schema_name ] . 
    | schema_name .
    ]
    table_or_view_name}
```

For other data base engines it could differ

Answer (score 3):

Like the others say, `Sales` could mean a schema or database. In MySQL it's a database name in MSSQL it's a schema name.

Answer (score 2):

`Sales` is the schema (or database) name, `Store` is the table name.

In your case, just omit the schema name, like this:

```
UPDATE  ContentTable
SET     field = @value
WHERE   id = @id
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the `@` symbols (SQL server, perhaps?), but `Sales.Store` is a table name.  In particular `Sales` appears to be a schema name and `Store` is the name of a table within that schema.